# RoR - how do I make remote_form_for insert new code alongside existing code instead of replacing it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using remote_form_for in Ruby on Rails to create a form that, once submitted, inserts some HTML into the existing page. I want the user to be able to use this pop-up to insert HTML more than once, but right now it just replaces the information that was there before.  How do I make it insert the new HTML alongside the existing HTML? (I've removed opening and closing tags in the code for readability).

```
remote_form_for  :quiz_questions,
                 :url => add_additional_cms_quiz_questions_path,
                 :update => "quiz_questions",
                 :success => 'toggle_hidden("new_question", false);' do |f|
  @quiz_question = QuizQuestion.new
  f.fields_for @quiz_question do |builder|
    render 'quiz_question', :f => builder
  end
  submit_tag 'Add Question'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [link_to_remote](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote) there is a way to pass an options hash that you can specify the `options[:position]` as `{:before|:top|:bottom|:after}`.

ps. I'm not 100% sure this will work, but it is worth a try.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I thinK I actually had that page up in my browser but couldn't find the solution.  Thank you!